# JAVA_HOME points to bin even though it does not

Tags: windows

Help! I've set JAVA_HOME to point to the Java jdk, however, when I execute the command `echo %JAVA_HOME%`, it still returns the bin directory. This is after I've opened up a new command prompt

[image]

[image]

This is my Path variable in user variables
[image]

Comment: This is more of a windows question than a java question.

Comment: either it points to bin, or it doesn't. It can't be both. don't post links to images on external sources, if you need to post images, edit them in your question.

Comment: Did you check "User Variables"? Maybe it's pointing to bin.

Comment: Did you restart the CMD session? just close it and re-open it.

Comment: Hi all, I've restarted the command prompt and also made sure user variable points to the jdk as well

Comment: @confegswl for all we know, that top screen is an edit, and you didn't press OK

Comment: @Stultuske first of all I did press OK, second I'm asking a genuine question, why would I edit the picture?

Comment: Why are you looking at the `%PATH%` environment variable when trying to figure out an issue with the `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable?

Comment: @IInspectable @Giorgi Tsiklauri suggested I check the `Path` environment variable

Comment: @confegswl I wasn't talking about "editing the picture", I was saying this might as well be a screenshot of you editing the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are showing only the "system variables". The "user variables" may include a new path to bin.

Comment: Hi Francisco, I've checked user variables and it doesnt

Comment: @confegswl check the `Path` environment variable.. it should be including something..

Comment: @gio Why would the contents of the `%PATH%` environment variable matter?